# How to get the Calendar dates in between?

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get the dates in between the calendar, but for some reason this does not work. Any suggestions why? Thanks.

```
public boolean verifyDate(Calendar cal) {       
    Calendar toDate  =  Calendar.getInstance();
    toDate.setTime(passToDate);
    Calendar fromDate  =  Calendar.getInstance();
    fromDate.setTime(passFromDate);
    return !((fromDate.after(cal) && toDate.before(cal)) || DateUtils.isSameDay(fromDate, cal) || DateUtils.isSameDay(toDate, cal));
}
```

Comment: What do you need? The number of days between two dates? Or to verify a date? If yes, against what?

Comment: I need to get a range of selected dates, from start to finish. I wrote a JUnit test and the start and finish dates work fine, although when I try to get the middle date, it doesn't work. e.g if I select 20th of July to 25 of July, it takes into consideration the dates : 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 and 25

Comment: I believe you have `fromDate` and `toDate` the wrong way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fromDate.after(cal) - will return `true` if `fromDate` will be after the `cal`, similar thing with `before`.

If you want to check that cal is between two dates use:

```
return cal.after(fromDate) && cal.before(toDate) 
    && !(DateUtils.isSameDay(fromDate, cal) || DateUtils.isSameDay(toDate, cal));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> getDates(String startDate, String endDate)
            throws ParseException, java.text.ParseException {
        List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (startDate == null || startDate.equals("") || endDate == null || endDate.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }


        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();


        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1 = dateFormat.parse(startDate);
        Date d2 = dateFormat.parse(endDate);

        Calendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar2.setTime(d2);
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        calendar.setTime(d1);

        while (calendar.getTime().before(calendar2.getTime()))
        {
            Date result = calendar.getTime();
            dateList.add(dateFormat.format(result));
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }


        return dateList;
    }
```